# CAN I raise custom SCOM Alerts in BizTalk

Tags: events, biztalk, biztalk-2010, alerts, mom

I need to check that all three of the required files in a set have been FTP'd before doing further processing on them. If all three files for the previous day have not arrived by 08:00 I need to raise and alert to a support person to contact the supplier. (Event 1)

If all three files are there, I then check the totals equal the transactions and if not I discard all three files and raise an alert to a support person to contact the supplier (Event 2)

I have the BizTalk (2010) - SCOM Management Pack loaded and need to know if I can create a custom rule that will raise and event for SCOM to detect, upon which I need SCOM to send a scenario-specific email to a recipient (e.g. Event 1 - All Three Required Files not Available! // or // Event 2 - Sum of transactions cannot be reconciled with Totals File)

We have looked at creating a SQL table for the message event log and defining custom processes for each connection point but it is clumsy, and I was advised that the above manner could be achieved, letting SCOM handle the Alert sending based on Events being raised by the process in BizTalk even though they are more BUSINESS events than SERVICE events.

Please advise - we have been going round in circles with this for two or three weeks now.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I had a similar problem at a client site a few months ago and was trying to achieve an alert through SCOM if a single message had not been received over FTP within a certain time. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any reliable documentation on achieving this with SCOM, so we went down the SQL table route which I am happy to document if you are interested. It certainly wasn't 'clumsy'.

Answer (score 0):

SCOM doesn't have anything out of the box like you are describing.
I do think you are looking at custom work here as Nick has suggested.

Another option is BizTalk360 does offer this feature.  It is called "[Process Monitoring](http://blogs.digitaldeposit.net/saravana/post/2012/08/08/BizTalk360-Process-Monitoring-Capabilities.aspx)" but would require a software license.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use Business Activity Monitoring (BAM) and raise alerts in there.